# When using Nokogiri, how do you suppress the insertion of self-closing tags?

Tags: ruby, jenkins, nokogiri

My XML doc, which is the config file for a Jenkins job, has a lot of empty tags like:

```
<string></string>
```

which Nokogiri replaces with:

```
<string/>
```

While this is the "recommended" way to write XML, it ends up generating unnecessary changes to the XML that make it difficult to read the meaningful content changes.  Is there a way to suppress this behavior?

Comment: While the title of the supposed duplicate sounds identical to this question, the duplicate's answers do not address the problem in the context of nokogiri. It's reasonable to ask for a solution in *nokogiri*.

Comment: I agree, the suggested duplicate does not actually contain a Nokogiri solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`NO_EMPTY_TAGS` option](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node/SaveOptions):

```
doc.to_xml(:save_with => Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_EMPTY_TAGS)
```

or the rather more concise:

```
doc.to_xml &:no_empty_tags
```

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. This solution has the unintended consequence of turning an empty tag like <actions/> into <actions></actions>.  While this ultimately results in a lesser number of differences, it would be ideal if this option could be combined with another option and/or transformation that would ensure the original XML is left as-is for functionally equivalent nodes.