# Nokogiri removes closing tags to some nodes I want with a closing tag

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Is there a way to have Nokogiri not remove an ending tag to certain nodes. I have the following node, and when I write my xml file with changes I'm losing an ending tag on it:

Before my modifications, it looks like this:

```
<Catalog name="example" version="3"></Catalog>
```

After modifications:

```
<Catalog name="example" version="3"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NO_EMPTY_TAGS option:

```
doc.to_xml(:save_with => Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_EMPTY_TAGS)
```

or the rather more concise:

```
doc.to_xml &:no_empty_tags
```

[When using Nokogiri, how do you suppress the insertion of self-closing tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416406/when-using-nokogiri-how-do-you-suppress-the-insertion-of-self-closing-tags)